# Calculating time difference between events in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-08-12T10:30:14.6938893+10:00     Reading received START |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:14.6938893+10:00       Reading received ADD |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:14.7094893+10:00    Reading received UPDATE |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:14.7094893+10:00    Reading received COMMIT |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:14.7094893+10:00               Commit start |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:14.7406893+10:00                 Commit end |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:14.7406893+10:00    Reading received FINISH |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:23.3206893+10:00     Reading received START |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:23.3206893+10:00       Reading received ADD |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:23.3362893+10:00    Reading received UPDATE |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:23.3362893+10:00    Reading received COMMIT |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:23.3362893+10:00               Commit start |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:23.3674893+10:00                 Commit end |
| 2014-08-12T10:30:23.3674893+10:00    Reading received FINISH |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Given a time series where the value describes an event, how can I calculate delta times between recurring events, e.g. the average difference between **Reading received START** and the subsequent **Reading received FINISH**?

Is there a better way than then e.g.

```
left = df[df.Event == 'Reading received START']
right = df[df.Event == 'Reading received FINISH']
left.index = range(len(left))
right.index = range(len(right))
delta = (right.Time - left.Time)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be explicit, I'm assuming that you are showing the index and one column (called 'Event') from a larger dataframe. Is that correct?
How about the following:

```
relevant_df = df[df.Event.isin(['Reading received START','Reading received START'])
relevant_ts_as_series = pd.Series(relevant_df.index)
diff = relevant_ts_as_series - relevant_ts_as_series.shift()
```

Then you can take `diff.mean()` if you like.

I bet there's a more elegant way than turning the index into a Series, but this should work for you.

Comment: You should be able to just call `diff()` on the series rather subtracting a `shift()`, strangely it can be marginally slower in some cases

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about `diff()`. In that case I probably shouldn't use it as a variable!

Comment: Hm, good answer but not as elegant as I hoped. I'll mark it since my original question is rather vague