# Time between events (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to find the time elapsed between 2 events A and B. More specifically, whenever event A occurs, I want to know how long it takes before the next occurence of event B.

Take a look at this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)
strings=list('AB')
data=[strings[i] for i in np.random.randint(0,2,15)]
index=pd.date_range('2/2/2012',periods=15,freq='T')
dfm=pd.DataFrame(data={'event':data},index=index)
dfm

                  event
2012-02-02 00:00:00 B
2012-02-02 00:01:00 A
2012-02-02 00:02:00 B
2012-02-02 00:03:00 B
2012-02-02 00:04:00 A
2012-02-02 00:05:00 A
2012-02-02 00:06:00 A
2012-02-02 00:07:00 B
2012-02-02 00:08:00 A
2012-02-02 00:09:00 A
2012-02-02 00:10:00 B
2012-02-02 00:11:00 A
2012-02-02 00:12:00 B
2012-02-02 00:13:00 A
2012-02-02 00:14:00 A
```

My expected output is:

```
begin           end
2012-02-02 00:01:00 2012-02-02 00:02:00 
2012-02-02 00:04:00 2012-02-02 00:07:00
2012-02-02 00:05:00 2012-02-02 00:07:00
2012-02-02 00:06:00 2012-02-02 00:07:00
2012-02-02 00:08:00 2012-02-02 00:10:00
2012-02-02 00:09:00 2012-02-02 00:10:00
2012-02-02 00:11:00 2012-02-02 00:12:00
```

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300582/calculating-time-difference-between-events-in-pandas) but is more complex since multiple A events can occur before a B event. I've thought quite a bit about a proper solution but haven't managed to come up with something that does the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `searchsorted` to find the indices where the start dates would be inserted into an array of end dates
while maintaining the end dates in sorted order. This array of indices tells you which end date to associate with each start date.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)
strings = list('AB')
data = [strings[i] for i in np.random.randint(0, 2, 15)]
index = pd.date_range('2/2/2012', periods=15, freq='T')
dfm = pd.DataFrame(data={'event': data}, index=index)


begin = dfm.loc[dfm['event'] == 'A'].index
cutoffs = dfm.loc[dfm['event'] == 'B'].index

idx = cutoffs.searchsorted(begin)
mask = idx < len(cutoffs)
idx = idx[mask]
begin = begin[mask]
end = cutoffs[idx]

result = pd.DataFrame({'begin':begin, 'end':end})
```

yields

```
                begin                 end
0 2012-02-02 00:01:00 2012-02-02 00:02:00
1 2012-02-02 00:04:00 2012-02-02 00:07:00
2 2012-02-02 00:05:00 2012-02-02 00:07:00
3 2012-02-02 00:06:00 2012-02-02 00:07:00
4 2012-02-02 00:08:00 2012-02-02 00:10:00
5 2012-02-02 00:09:00 2012-02-02 00:10:00
6 2012-02-02 00:11:00 2012-02-02 00:12:00
```

---

The [`DatetimeIndex.searchsorted` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.searchsorted.html) 
is not heavily documented, but it is mainly [a thin wrapper](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/index.py#L1463) around a call to [numpy.searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) 
which can handle dates represented as numpy `datetime64`s.